# Android back button behaviour issue...

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onbackpressed

I have been using finish() for back button presses to go back to previous activity and its working fine but it is not working as expected for this specific scenario.

**Here are a list of my activities and its functions:**

Activity A - Show online forum topics

Activity B - Show the comments of a forum topic

Activity C - Post a new comment

After a user post a new comment, he will be directed to activity B.

**Issue:**

When i click on back button on Activity B, it will go back to Activity C, because it was my previous activity.

Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C -> Activity B ***-> Activity C -> Activity B -> Activity A***

**Expectation**

I want the user to go back to activity A from activity B at all cause.

Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C -> Activity B ***-> Activity A***

I tried using intent to only direct Activity B to A upon back pressed, but it is reloading the data on Activity A which i do not want.

Codes I tried:

```
case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
//this works if i am only going back and forth one activity

case android.R.id.home:
 Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.putExtra("forumLink", forumLink);
            i.putExtra("forumTitle", forumTitle);
            startActivity(i);
//this refreshes Activity A data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `finish()` on `Activity C` before going from **C** to **B**.

You can make `Activity A` as parent of **B** ,and **B** as parent of **C**

Comment: Thanks so much!! It works!! I will take note of making Activity A as parent to B and such.

Answer (score 0):

You have to kill Activity C before going to activity B.
Since your activity c exits, thats why it is going to activity c.
So, use finish() to kill activity c. Killing the activity c will redirect you to activity b.